# What is the simplest visa requirement for a New Zealander to work in Argentina?

Tags: visas, work, argentina, new-zealand-citizens

Considering this. I gather there's a working holiday visa, but it requires application at the embassy in WELLINGTON, and I'm ... well, on the other side of the world.

What would be the simplest method of gaining eligibility to work in Argentina, or will I just have to bite the bullet and fire my passport off to NZ?  Can one not get a work permit in Buenos Aires, for example?

(yes, I have met people working under the table there, but if there's an easy way to get a visa, that's better)

Comment: People from NZ working under the table? How do they...fit in there - are they hobbits?

Comment: oh har-har :) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=under%20the%20table

Comment: What does mean `har` on hobbit language?

Comment: @MarkMayo Oi. Don't patronise me. :p

Comment: http://www.justlanded.de/espanol/Argentina/Guia-Argentina/Empleo/Permisos-de-Trabajo

Comment: or in English: http://www.justlanded.de/english/Argentina/Argentina-Guide/Jobs/Work-Permits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a link as provided in the comments about [Argentina Work Permits and how to apply for them](http://www.justlanded.de/english/Argentina/Argentina-Guide/Jobs/Work-Permits).

The requirements to apply for a work visa are:

- Labour contract with the company or institution in Argentina
- Birth certificate, translated into Spanish by a certified translator
- Marital certification, translated into Spanish by a certified translator (if an application is being made for a spouse)
- Passport with a minimum validity of 18 months remaining (for each family member)
- 3 passport photo’s for each family member (4x4; preferably light blue background; ¾ profile right side)

The most common types of work visas are:

- Article 29 (e) visas – This visa is a short term visa and is issued for short term work in Argentina. The initial validity is of 15 days and can be extended for another 15 days once in Argentina.
- Article 15 (E) visa (Labour Contract – Temporary Residence Visa) – This visa is issued for employees and people on internships contracted by companies in Argentina. The minimum duration is 6–12 months. You will be treated as a local employee that means a CUIL has to be applied for as well. A formal labour contract between the company in Argentina and the employee is required in order to obtain the visa.
- Article 15 (E) visa (Secondment – Temporary Residence Visa) under provision 18/94 – This visa is issued to employees send abroad by their company for at least 6–12 months. A labour contract is not required

Notes:

- Persons having a contract with an Argentinean company or institution also have to sign an employment agreement in the presence of the consul (there is usually a supplementary charge for this made by the consulate)
- Persons sent to Argentina by foreign companies have to sign their labour agreement at the corresponding company.
- Spouses and children of applicants of a temporary working permit that want a permit to live in Argentina have to show proof of the family ties. This can be done by means of a marriage certificate and/or birth certificates at an international form.

Once employees arrive in Argentina, they also need to apply for a DNI/ National Identity Document and a CUIL/ Unique Code for Work Identification.